# Replace dot product operator in mathematical formula

Tags: python, regex, replace

How can I replace pythons internal sign of dot product (@) to numpy's numpy.dot instead? As an example, the formula
`m.a@x + m.b@y` should be transformed into `np.dot(m.a, x) + np.dot(m.b, y)`.

My initial thought was to use regex to find the text before and after the @ (`m.a` and `m.b` in above example) and then put them in the dot function. Here's how I imagine doing it with regex:

```
# m.a, m.b, x and y are vectors of some equal size
formula = "m.a@x + m.b@y"
before_dots, after_dots = some_regex_function(formula)
result = eval(f"np.dot({before_dot[0]},{after_dot[0]}) + np.dot({before_dot[1]},{after_dot[1]})")
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are using regex. If you show your try, maybe we can better understand to help you.

Comment: What did you try? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Maybe @ is not an operator in Python, but if you execute x@y for some vectors x and y, you do not decorate but compute the dot product of x and y.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, `@` was indeed introduced in Python 3.5.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I updated the question, maybe it's more clear what I'm trying to do. I realize there must be confusion since I'm talking about strings and dot product. I'm using ```eval``` to compute

Comment: Python is not a regular language, so you cannot use regular expressions to parse it. Check the `ast` module in Python if you want to parse Python source code like this.

Comment: numpy directly supports the `@` operator, why do you need to make any transformation here?

Comment: @jasonharper it does? Do you know how to set Python to use numpy's dot product when computing with @?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seek is indeed solvable with regex but make sense only if you are trying to do it in multiple files at a time.
Also, there should be no emails in these files as emails are verymuch a subset of this regex pattern and would almost always match.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/I8cyM4/1) is the regex I wrote that hopefully covers all the possible cases.

To do it for multiple files, I would suggest using it with `perl` as

```sh
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=[^_a-zA-Z])([_a-zA-Z][\w\._]*)@([_a-zA-Z][\w\._]*)(\1|(?=\s))/np.dot(\1, \2)/g'
```

`-i` option changes the file inplace

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ast` and `astor` modules, you can parse the code and replace all binary operation nodes where the operator is matrix multiplication with a `np.dot` call.

```
import ast
import astor


class ReplaceNpDot(astor.TreeWalk):
    def post_BinOp(self):
        node = self.cur_node
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.MatMult):
            np = ast.Name(id="np", ctx=ast.Load())
            np_dot = ast.Attribute(np, 'dot', ctx=ast.Load())
            self.replace(ast.Call(
                np_dot,
                args=[node.left, node.right],
                keywords=[],
                startargs=[]
            ))
        else:
            return node


# define m so it works...
# ...

# replace @ with np.dot
tree = ast.parse("m.a@x + m.b@y", mode='eval')
walker = ReplaceNpDot()
walker.walk(tree)

# print source code
print(astor.to_source(tree))

# run code
code = compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(tree), '<string>', 'eval')
exec(code)
```